# How to exit from command "docker start mysql -a"

Tags: docker

I just restart my docker container with `docker start mysql -a`, and the container logs print on my terminal screen.

After all logs are output, I can not exit from that command, even if I use `ctrl + C`. So is there any way I can exit from that command?

[Check the screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k48vN.jpg)

Comment: use `docker stop out-mysql` to stop the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `docker start out-mysql -a` to start a container in attached mode.
In docker docs, if you see what does -a options does is, it will show the following:

```
Options:
  -a, --attach               Attach STDOUT/STDERR and forward signals
```

So using `Ctrl+C` won't stop the container.

### Solution

> Open a new terminal tab/window and type the following command to stop the container.
>
> ```
> docker stop out-mysql
> ```

Comment: Yeah, I have checked the docker docs, and I'm not quite understand that explanation. Thank you, I will open another terminal to stop that container.